# How to bind CommandParameter and get selected row id in radgridview

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like modify row with clicked button in my table.

Its my code :

view model :

```
        public class PrzeszukiwanieBazyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ModelBazyDanych _modelBazy;
        private IList<EwidencjonowanaRzecz> _ewidencjaList;
        private String _test;

        public string Test
        {
            get { return _test; }
            set
            {
                if (value == _test) return;
                _test = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public IList<EwidencjonowanaRzecz> EwidencjaList
        {
            get { return _ewidencjaList; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _ewidencjaList)) return;
                _ewidencjaList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }


        public PrzeszukiwanieBazyViewModel(ModelBazyDanych pModelBazyDanych)
        {
            this._modelBazy = pModelBazyDanych;
            LocalizationManager.Manager = new Jezyk();
//            EwidencjaList = ModelBazy.SelectAllFromTable<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>().Where(m => m.Status == 0).ToList();
        }

        public ModelBazyDanych ModelBazy
        {
            get { return _modelBazy; }
            set
            {
                if (Equals(value, _modelBazy)) return;
                _modelBazy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _odswiezanieCommand;
        public ICommand OdswiezanieCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_odswiezanieCommand == null)
                    _odswiezanieCommand = new DelegateCommand(Odswiezanie);
                return _odswiezanieCommand;
            }
        }
        private DelegateCommand _wydajCommand;
        public ICommand WydajCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_wydajCommand == null)
                    _wydajCommand = new DelegateCommand(Wydaj);
                return _wydajCommand;
            }
        }

        private void Wydaj()
        {
            // HOW TO WRITE THIS ?:>
        }

        private void Odswiezanie()
        {
//            MessageBox.Show(Test);
            EwidencjaList = ModelBazy.SelectAllFromTable<EwidencjonowanaRzecz>().Where(m => m.Status == 0).ToList();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

XAML:

```
   <controls:RadGridView 
                             Grid.Row="0"
                             x:Name="TableRadGridView"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=PrzeszukiwanieBazyViewModel.EwidencjaList}"
                             AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                             ColumnWidth="auto"
                             FilteringMode="Popup"
                             BorderThickness="0">
                    <controls:RadGridView.Columns>
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Id}" Header="Id" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Nazwa}" Header="Nazwa" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Model}" Header="Model" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Marka}" Header="Marka" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding WagaRef.WagaPrzedmiotu}" Header="Waga" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding KolorRef.Barwa}" Header="Kolor" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding GdzieZnaleziono}" Header="Gdzie znaleziono" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding KtoZnalazl}" Header="Kto znalazł" />

                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Marka}" Header="Uwagi" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding KategoriaRef.Nazwa}" Header="Kategoria" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding UserRef.Login}" Header="Dodane przez" />
                        <controls:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding Status}" Header="Status" />
                <controls:GridViewDataColumn Header="Wydaj">
                   <controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                            <controls:RadButton Content="Wydaj"
                                                Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=PrzeszukiwanieBazyViewModel.WydajCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="qwerty"></controls:RadButton>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </controls:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:GridViewDataColumn>


            </controls:RadGridView.Columns>
                </controls:RadGridView>
```

When i click button in selected row , i would like to change field "Status" in this record. My only idea to get selected row is CommandParameter. How can i implement sth like this ? How to write "Wydaj()" function in VM ?

Answer (score 1):

First off, the `ICommand.ExecuteCommand` method typically takes one object parameter, so its implementation should look like this:

```
private void Wydaj(object parameter)
{
    if (parameter as EwidencjonowanaRzecz != null)
        ((EwidencjonowanaRzecz)parameter).Status = "new status";
}
```

(Most implementations of `ICommand`, including Telerik's `DelegateCommand`, would allow you to pass this directly in the constructor, as you have it: `_wydajCommand = new DelegateCommand(Wydaj);`)

Next, update the `CommandParameter`, bind it to the row data:

```
<controls:RadButton Content="Wydaj"
                    Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator},Path=PrzeszukiwanieBazyViewModel.WydajCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic version of [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22MICROSOFT.PRACTICES.PRISM.COMMANDS.DELEGATECOMMAND%601%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true).  I'm assuming that your CommandParameter is a String, so you can declare it like so

```
private DelegateCommand<String> _wydajCommand;
public ICommand WydajCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_wydajCommand == null)
            _wydajCommand = new DelegateCommand<String>(Wydaj);
        return _wydajCommand;
    }
}
```

and the Execute handler function can be

```
private void Wydaj(String parameter)
```

Comment: Ah, good!  I was about to say that McGarnagle appeared to have a better answer, because I didn't know about the Telerik DelegateCommand.  However, if this works, then 'nuff said.